# Printing jenkins credentials Id

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, sh

Does anyone know how I can print credentials stored in jenkins?
Below script throws:

```
Unexpected exception caught! groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: crd for class: com.test.File
```

Here is my code:

service.groovy

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(
    credentialsId: vaultCredentialId, usernameVariable: 'ID', passwordVariable: 'CRED')]){


sh """
    crd=${CRED}
    for chars in `echo $crd | fold -w1`; do echo "value: $chars" ; done
"""
```

Comment: It's unclear from your question why do you want to print credentials stored in Jenkins. If you have forgotten them, there's a way to decode without running pipeline.

Comment: @MaratC I never said why I needed to print them, but you appear curious by nature so i will tell you why :) We have a team that maintains Jenkins env and they add credentials for us. I do not have a way of seeing them or any of it. I was suspicious by the error I was getting that it could be the credentials issue. That is why I wanted to print them. Which turned out to be exactly the problem.

Comment: I already answered you, but FYI $crd is been handled as Groovy variable and is never declared, If you wanted to use as a bash variable then you had to escape it \$crd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'withCredentials' step will mask any output matching it secrets so If you want to display them you have to do it outside the step.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label "master"
    }
    
    stages {
        stage("run") {
            steps {
                script {
                    userVar = null
                    passVar = null
                    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'administrator-jenkins', passwordVariable: 'password', usernameVariable: 'username')]) {
                        userVar = username
                        passVar = password
                    }
                    echo "Username: ${userVar}"
                    echo "Password: ${passVar}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```